# PHP autoload own classes and AWS SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I've tried to use the AWS SDK according to this:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html

I've tried both the .phar-file and unpacking the zip but I run into issues.

I use the __autoload function in PHP like this:

```
// autoload classes
function __autoload($class) {
    require_once ('./system/classes/'.strtolower($class).'.php');
}
```

This works fine by itself. However, I include the SDK like so:

```
require '/path/to/aws.phar';
```

My system cannot find my own classes any more (the ones that hasn't been called yet at the time I include AWS SDK that is).

What am I missing? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Use the composer one, by far the easiest.

Comment: Use what works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is because using the `__autoload` method you can only have one autoloader, and aws needs to add its own autloader. It is much better to use `spl_autoload_register`, as this allows for multiple autoload functions, so yours will still be available even when aws.phar has added it's own.

Try this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once ('./system/classes/'.strtolower($class).'.php');
});
```

See docs on this here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: I have much to learn I guess. Many thanks, I'll try this out!

Comment: I would also recommend you take a look at Composer https://getcomposer.org/ which not only manages dependencies of other libraries in php, but allows you to easily configure your own classes to autoload.

Answer (score 1):

It is not to difficult to learn the [PHP-FIG SP4 autoload](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standard and do it yourself. This uses [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) and you can use more than one autoloader. Here is an example of a do-it-yourself autoloader class I made just reading the PHP-FIG standards and the PHP manual.

```
<?php
namespace Acme\Framework;  //Just to use namespaces in this example.

class Autoloader
{
    private function __construct()
    {
        ;
    }

    private function __clone()
    {
        ;
    }

    private static function autoload($qualifiedClassName)
    {
        $nsPrefix = 'Acme\\';
        $baseDir  = 'C:/public/www/acme/src/'; // /public/www/acme/src/
        $nsPrefixLength = strlen($nsPrefix);

        if (strncmp($nsPrefix, $qualifiedClassName, $nsPrefixLength) !== 0) {
            return; //Go to next registered autoloader function / method.
        }

        $file = $baseDir . str_replace('\\', '/', substr($qualifiedClassName, $nsPrefixLength)) . '.php';  //substr() returns the string after $nsPrefix.

        if (!file_exists($file)){
            echo "<h1>$file</h1>";
            throw new \RuntimeException("The file {$file} does not exist!");
        }

        if (!is_file($file)){
            throw new \RuntimeException("The file {$file} is not a regular file!");
        }

        if (!is_readable($file)){
            throw new \RuntimeException("The file {$file} is not readable!");
        }

        require $file;
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        /*
          Just make another method in this class and alter this code
          to run spl_autoload_register() twice.
        */

        if(!spl_autoload_register(['self', 'autoload']))
        {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Autoloader failed to initialize spl_autoload_register().');
        }
    }
}
```

I use it like this during bootstrap time.

```
require 'Autoloader.php';   //Autoloader for objects.
Autoloader::init();
```

This could be altered to support another autoloader for code in a different directory.

I hope this was helpful. Good luck to you, and may your project be a success!

Sincerely,

Anthony Rutledge